# How can I query all users who registered today?

Tags: query, meta-query, date, users

I'm trying to use `meta_query` to return all users that have registered today :

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'user_registered',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$users = $query->get_results();
```

This doesn't seem to work though. What am I missing ?

Comment: Yes, there were changes made in 4.1 and the `WP_User_Query` class now supports a `WP_Date_Query` query on the user registration date. I used it in my [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/196774/26350) and updated the Codex at that time.

Comment: Hi, @mike23 - There's now a more up to date answer to your question below. Would you mind changing the accepted answer for the benefit of future Googlers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few months ago, I updated the Codex for [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/get_users) and [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query), regarding the `date_query` support on the *user's registration date*, in WordPress 4.1+.

Then I also added a [simple example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Date_Parameters) on how to find users that registered during the last 12 hours.

But the current question is how to find users that registered *today*.

We could simply use relative date string:

```
$args = [
    'date_query' => [
        [ 'after'  => 'today', 'inclusive' => true ],
    ] 
];

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

that will generate the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* FROM wp_users WHERE 1=1 AND ( 
    wp_users.user_registered >= '2015-11-06 00:00:00'
) ORDER BY user_login ASC ;
```

We might also set the `year`, `month` and `day` parameters explicitly:

```
$args = [
    'date_query' => [
        [   
            'year'  => current_time( 'Y' ),
            'month' => current_time( 'm' ),
            'day'   => current_time( 'd' ),
        ],
    ] 
];

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

that will generate:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* FROM wp_users WHERE 1=1 AND ( 
    ( 
        YEAR( wp_users.user_registered ) = 2015 
        AND MONTH( wp_users.user_registered ) = 11 
        AND DAYOFMONTH( wp_users.user_registered ) = 6 
    )
) ORDER BY user_login ASC ;
```

Answer (score 11):

The field `user_registered` is not a in the `*_usermeta` table, but the in `*_users`.

Nor do there seem to be any appropriate hooks to alter the SQL statement when using `WP_User_Query`. It seems you will need to use a direct SQL statement.

Another (minor) complication is that the registered date is stored as a date-time.

```
function wpse51485_get_users_registered_on( $date='' ){
    global $wpdb;

    if( empty($date) )
        $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $morning = new DateTime($date. ' 00:00:00');
    $night = new DateTime($date.' 23:59:59'); 
    $m = $morning->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $n = $night->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT wp_users.* FROM wp_users WHERE 1=1 AND CAST(user_registered AS DATE) BETWEEN %s AND %s ORDER BY user_login ASC",$m,$n);

    $users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return $users;
 }
```